# Git clone with user and password

Tags: git

I'm using Git on Windows with LDAP. No issue so far.

When I'm cloning my remote repository I call:

git clone http://user@host.com/name/.git
and I got a prompt for password

This is working. But now I will run a script and clone without password prompt.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Duplicate on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git) has more substantial answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put it in the URL.

```
http://user:password@host.com/name/.git
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but this was not working. SYSTEM answers: sh.exe: event not found

Comment: That's because your shell is consuming the `!` in your password. Escape or encode it.

Comment: is there an option to store the password in a file like on Star Team stcmd.exe co -epwdfile "pw.txt" -p "$user:@host"

Comment: You can set the `core.askpass` option to a program that will output the password on stdout, but nothing built-in.

Comment: I found an escape character for @ -> %40 for example but non for !

Comment: `>>> hex(ord('!'))`
`'0x21'`

Comment: Still having trouble here In case I use 0x21 in the password my system take 0x21 as string. my command git clone http://user:password_with_1@host.com....

Comment: You should use `%21`, not `0x21`. `0x21` is the hexadecimal byte notation for `!`, `%21` is the URL encoding notation for `!`.